# How to change a project's name in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Is there a way to change a .pro , .ui and .h names if the project is done? How to do it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Names for `.ui`, `.h` and `.cpp` files can just be changed inside Qt Creator.

The name of the `.pro` file is a bit more involved. The simplest is probably to copy the project, rename the `.pro` file, and reopen.

Qt Creator also uses its own config file, `.pro.user`, for changes you do in the project and build settings. You can just delete the `.pro.user`-file, and it'll generate a new one. If you've made changes to the settings and the build process, you can rename that file as well, but remember to read through it and check build paths etc.

Edit by anonymous: Run qmake to generate a new Makefile with updated references to the project name

Comment: thx. what about a form name and it's .h and cpp files from this .pro project

Comment: And what about if the project is also bound to a local (and maybe remote) Git repository or other version control?

Comment: could you please explain how to run qmake to generate a new makefile ? @gund

Answer (score 20):

- Open the terminal or folder structure where the current project is stored; e.g. in Linux you may right click on .pro file and "open in terminal"
- Close the Qt creator completely
- Rename the containing folder also to `new_name`
- Rename the `old_name.pro` to `new_name.pro`
- Inside the `new_name.pro`, rename the `TARGET = new_name`
- You may delete the debug & release folders of `old_name` project which were stored in parallel to the `old_name` folder
- Restart the Qt creator; Open the project `new_name.pro`

This answer is inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6874140/514235).

Comment: Very useful, I'd also suggest deleting the .pro.user cache files since they won't be used after changing the project's name.

Comment: This works perfectly with QtCreator 4.8.2. Only thing to do after this is to set the default kit for the project again.

Answer (score 2):

go to folder there is your project

cp current_name.pro  new_name.pro  && rm current_name.pro

qt will show you warning message  , ignore

with qt(open project) reopen your folder, open  new_name.pro

Answer (score 0):

### This  worked for me  I am on Fedora 35 running QT5.
Close QT then run this script.
I didn't  find any .pro files. and I didn't get any error messages after running this and doing the rebuild.

```
  #/bin/bash
  #Wed Aug 10 10:30:12 AM EDT 2022
  # how to copy a QT project to a new name
  set -x

  echo -n enter oldname
  read oldName

  echo -n enter newname
  read newName

  cp -a "$oldName" "$newName"

  mv "$newName/$oldName.pro" "$newName/$newName.pro"
  mv "$newName/$oldName.pro.user" "$newName/$newName.pro.user"

  sed -i "s/$oldName/$newName/g" "$newName/$newName.pro.user"

  echo "Now startup Qt and open existing file    $newName/$newName.pro"
  echo "and run a build all configurations"
```

------end of bash script------------